# Displaying data with styles in MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am storing data entered from a rich text editor to database as an html string with font settings in MVC3 Razor. 
eg: **Bold Red**

In another page I have to displaying back this info along with the styles . I tried to display it as

```
<label id="lblDisplay" >@Html.Raw(@Model.IncidentDescription)</label>
```

where `@model.IncidentDescription` have value 
`<strong><span style="color:#ff0000">Bold Red</span></strong>` . But it is only displaying "Bold Red" with out the style settings. How can I get my style settings displayed in a .cshtml page?

Comment: have you used Chrome's dev tool or FireBug in FF to check the markup that was written?

Comment: Are you sure that `Model.IncidentDescription` has a value of `<strong><span style="color:#ff0000">Bold Red</span></strong>`? Because I am not. Check once again.

Comment: I have given the answer. It is useful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
<label id="lblDisplay">
 @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Model.IncidentDescription))</label>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556008/html-raw-is-not-working-asp-net-mvc)