# Html.Raw() output is &amp; instead of &

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a canonical url in my controller and pass it on to my ViewModel to display it in the header.

The url string in my ViewModel is:

```
/books?page=4&pagesize=25
```

I have the following code:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.LinkCanonical))
{
    <link rel="canonical" href="@Html.Raw(Model.LinkCanonical)" />
}
```

And the output is:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/books?page=4&amp;pagesize=25" />
```

Afaik the `Html.Raw()` helper should output `&` instead of `&amp;`.

How can this happen?

**Edit:**

This solution works, and is already mentioned here: [Why is Html.Raw escaping ampersand in anchor tag in ASP.NET MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963453/why-is-html-raw-escaping-ampersand-in-anchor-tag-in-asp-net-mvc-4/11973960#11973960):

```
 @Html.Raw("<link rel=\"canonical\" href=" + Model.LinkCanonical + "\" />")
```

Comment: You don't want to use Html.Raw ... opens your site up to script injection attacks unless implemented very very carefully (the code you've posted means I can craft a post to your site which will send all logged in user's authentication cookies to another website and then hijack their sessions)

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct output - the browser will handle the html encoded ampersand and the URL will indeed point to `/books?page=4&pagesize=25` (try it!)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.LinkCanonical))" />
```

Comment: This gives me the same output

Comment: UrlDecode doesn't work either

Comment: well, i saw it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556008/html-raw-is-not-working-asp-net-mvc
and it seemed to work there!